# fetch request with form data for auth react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch

i'm trying to create a basic email input form with react and fetch.

I'm getting a series of errors that I don't fully understand where they're coming from.

i'm following https://mattboldt.com/2020/05/02/formdata-with-react-hooks-and-fetch/

Just want to keep it super simple. Trying to just send this to the auth api as a tester,

```
{"email":"oahnsodi@gmail.com","name":"aoisdnasd"}
```

essentially this is the component with the error.

```
function FormAlert(props) {
  const { type, message, ...otherProps } = props;

  return (

  <div>
        {type ==="error" ? "danger":"success"}
{}
  <div className="mx-auto flex items-center justify-center h-12 w-12 rounded-full bg-green-100">
    <CheckIcon className="h-6 w-6 text-green-600" aria-hidden="true" />
  </div>
  <div className="mt-3 text-center sm:mt-5">
    <Dialog.Title as="h3" className="text-lg leading-6 font-medium text-gray-900">
      Email successful
    </Dialog.Title>
    <div className="mt-2">
      <p className="text-sm text-gray-500">
        Welcome to the Plantform Movement!
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  )
};

const AuthForm =(props)=> {
  const [pending, setPending] = useState(false);
  // const { handleSubmit, register, errors, getValues } = useForm();
  const [user, setUser] = useState({ name: 'Sign Up!' })
  console.log(user)
  
  // Handle form submission
  const submit = e => {
    setPending(true);
    console.log({ "name":user[name],"email":user[email] })
    const payload = JSON.stringify({ "name":user[name],"email":user[email] })
  
    console.log(payload)

    e.preventDefault()
    fetch('xxxxx/fakeAuth', {
      method: 'POST',
      mode:'no-cors',
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },

      body:     payload,
    })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(json => setUser(json))
      .catch((error) => {
        // Show error alert message
        console.log(error)
      }) 
      .finally(() => {
        // Hide pending indicator
        setPending(false);
      });
  }

  
  return (
    <div className="pt-8">
          <div>
            <h3 className="text-lg leading-6 font-medium text-gray-900">Personal Information</h3>
            <p className="mt-1 text-sm text-gray-500">Use a permanent address where you can receive mail.</p>
          </div>
          <div className="mt-6 grid grid-cols-1 gap-y-6 gap-x-4 sm:grid-cols-6">
          <form onSubmit={submit}>

            <div className="sm:col-span-3">
              <label htmlFor="name" className="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700">
                Full name
              </label>
              <div className="mt-1 shadow-sm focus:ring-green-500 focus:border-green-500 block w-full sm:text-sm border-gray-300 rounded-md">
                <input
                  type="text"
                  name="user[name]"
                  id="name"
                  value={user.name}
                  onChange={e => setUser({ ...user, name: e.target.value })}
                  autoComplete="given-name"
                  className="shadow-sm focus:ring-green-500 focus:border-green-500 block w-full sm:text-sm border-gray-300 rounded-md"
                />
              </div>
            </div>

            

            <div className="sm:col-span-4">
              <label htmlFor="email" className="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700">
                Email address
              </label>
              <div className="mt-1">
                <input
                  id="email"
                  name="user[email]"
                  value={user.email}
                  onChange={e => setUser({ ...user, email: e.target.value })}

                  autoComplete="email"
                  className="shadow-sm focus:ring-green-500 focus:border-green-500 block w-full sm:text-sm border-gray-300 rounded-md"
                />
              </div>
            </div>


            <div className="sm:col-span-4">
              <label htmlFor="confirmEmail" className="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700">
                Confirm email 
              </label>
              <div className="mt-1">
                <input
                  id="confirmEmail"
                  name="confirmEmail"
                  type="confirmEmail"
                  autoComplete="confirmEmail"
                  className="shadow-sm focus:ring-green-500 focus:border-green-500 block w-full sm:text-sm border-gray-300 rounded-md"
                />
              </div>
            </div>
            
</form>

            

           
          </div>
          <div className="mt-5 sm:mt-6">
                <button
                type="submit"
                className="inline-flex justify-center w-full rounded-md border border-transparent shadow-sm px-4 py-2 bg-green-600 text-base font-medium text-white hover:bg-green-700 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-green-500 sm:text-sm"
                disabled={pending}
onClick = {submit}
                >
                   {!pending && <span>Submit</span>}

                {pending && (
                  <>
                    <svg
                      className="animate-spin -ml-1 mr-3 h-5 w-5 text-white"
                      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                      fill="none"
                      viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                    >
                      <circle
                        className="opacity-25"
                        cx="12"
                        cy="12"
                        r="10"
                        stroke="currentColor"
                        strokeWidth="4"
                      ></circle>
                      <path
                        className="opacity-75"
                        fill="currentColor"
                        d="M4 12a8 8 0 018-8V0C5.373 0 0 5.373 0 12h4zm2 5.291A7.962 7.962 0 014 12H0c0 3.042 1.135 5.824 3 7.938l3-2.647z"
                      ></path>
                    </svg>
                    <span>Please wait...</span>
                  </>
                )}
                </button>
              </div>
        </div>

  )
}
```

It's returning an error of

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Source
src/components/Authentication/AuthModal.js (84:30) @ AuthForm

  82 | name="user[name]"
  83 | id="name"
> 84 | value={user.name}
     |            ^
  85 | onChange={e => setUser({ ...user, name: e.target.value })}
  86 | autoComplete="given-name"
  87 | className="shadow-sm focus:ring-green-500 focus:border-green-500 block w-full sm:text-sm border-gray-300 rounded-md"
```

This is feeding into this high level component.

```
    /* This example requires Tailwind CSS v2.0+ */
import { Fragment, useState } from 'react'
import { Dialog, Transition } from '@headlessui/react'
import { CheckIcon } from '@heroicons/react/outline'

import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
// import { useRouter } from "next/router";


export default function AuthModal() {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  // setUser(name="")
  const [formAlert, setFormAlert] = useState(null);

  return (
<>
    <button
    className="bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded"
    onClick={() => setOpen(true)}
  >
    Signup
  </button>
   {open ? (
    <Transition.Root show={open} as={Fragment}>
      <Dialog as="div" static className="fixed z-10 inset-0 overflow-y-auto" open={open} onClose={setOpen}>
        <div className="flex items-end justify-center min-h-screen pt-4 px-4 pb-20 text-center sm:block sm:p-0">
          <Transition.Child
            as={Fragment}
            enter="ease-out duration-300"
            enterFrom="opacity-0"
            enterTo="opacity-100"
            leave="ease-in duration-200"
            leaveFrom="opacity-100"
            leaveTo="opacity-0"
          >
            <Dialog.Overlay className="fixed inset-0 bg-gray-500 bg-opacity-75 transition-opacity" />
          </Transition.Child>

          {/* This element is to trick the browser into centering the modal contents. */}
          <span className="hidden sm:inline-block sm:align-middle sm:h-screen" aria-hidden="true">
            &#8203;
          </span>
          <Transition.Child
            as={Fragment}
            enter="ease-out duration-300"
            enterFrom="opacity-0 translate-y-4 sm:translate-y-0 sm:scale-95"
            enterTo="opacity-100 translate-y-0 sm:scale-100"
            leave="ease-in duration-200"
            leaveFrom="opacity-100 translate-y-0 sm:scale-100"
            leaveTo="opacity-0 translate-y-4 sm:translate-y-0 sm:scale-95"
          >
            <div className="inline-block align-bottom bg-white rounded-lg px-4 pt-5 pb-4 text-left overflow-hidden shadow-xl transform transition-all sm:my-8 sm:align-middle sm:max-w-sm sm:w-full sm:p-6">
            {formAlert && (
                <div className="mx-auto flex items-center justify-center h-12 w-12 rounded-full bg-green-100">

        <FormAlert type={formAlert.type} message={formAlert.message} />
        </div>
      )}

            <AuthForm
        

            />
           
            </div>
          </Transition.Child>
        </div>
      </Dialog>
    </Transition.Root>
    ) : null}
    </>
  )
}
```

What I am doing wrong here? Should I just use react-hooks-forms? I just want to be able to create a minimal version of signing up by sending a json payload with email and name atm, and changing the state so that I have specific outcomes for this higher component.

### Made some updates, still unsure why I am getting 404 errors when pushing to the server, error looks like this now.

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
    at eval (AuthModal.js?5485:123)
```

and a 400 error, with this console log as an example,

```
{name: undefined, email: undefined}email: undefinedname: undefined__proto__: Object
AuthModal.js?5485:113 {}
AuthModal.js?5485:105 {name: "oaisdn091n2d", email: "12ed09j23podm@gmail.com"}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
const payload = JSON.stringify({ "name":user[name],"email":user[email] })
```

you need to pass name and email as string to user like these `user['name']` `user['email']` like these.